# CF7 - Database field validation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to validate my cf7 form with a custom list in the database. So if the user enters a value in the field that isn't in my list, the form will fail validation. Its a long list of 60,000 entries.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I recommend asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ And add a bit information about the list. Where/how is this list stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to use custom validation hook of cf7. You will need to do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );

if ( 'your-email-confirm' == $tag->name ) {
    $your_email = isset( $_POST['your-email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email'] ) : '';
    $your_email_confirm = isset( $_POST['your-email-confirm'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email-confirm'] ) : '';

    if ( $your_email != $your_email_confirm ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, "Are you sure this is the correct address?" );
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

This is a basic custom validation on email field, you need to customize like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_field_validation', 20, 2 );

function custom_field_validation( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );

global $wpdb;
$searchTerm = $wpdb->get_row('select * from ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'name_of_table where name_of_field = "' . $_POST['given_value'] . '"');

if(!$searchTerm)
    $result->invalidate( $tag, "Value doesn't match" );

return $result;
}
```

Also you can use wpcf7_validate_text instead of wpcf7_validate_mail if you are using text field

Comment: Thank you this is great - however, it applies to all my forms now. Is there a way to amend the above code to just apply to one CF& form?

Comment: could you introduce a control when you call filter add_action. If you want to apply this filter only a given page you can do this:

global $post; if($post->ID == 1) add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_field_validation', 20, 2 );

where 1 is your post or page id

Comment: I was struggling getting the post ID so used the url to check for a string. Then wrapped the whole function in an if statement. Thanks for your help!